# oracle, select query with average and sum

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with products put into types and also there cost, trying to output for each type how many products and average cost.eg:

```
category   No.   average price  
hats       12    10
```

But only one line for each category

```
select Category "Category", sum category "No.", average category "average Price"  
from table
```

I can't find any other examples of similar queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select   category, count(*) as categ_count, avg(price) as avg_price
from     table
group by category;
```

Don't use column names in double-quotes, that is a very poor practice in Oracle. Just make sure your column names follow the rules (only alphanumeric characters and underscore, begin with a letter, and don't use Oracle keywords like DATE or TYPE).

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have your table, lets use mine as an example.

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEES 
   (EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER(6,0), 
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(20), 
    LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(25) CONSTRAINT EMP_LAST_NAME_NN NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    EMAIL VARCHAR2(25) CONSTRAINT EMP_EMAIL_NN NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    PHONE_NUMBER VARCHAR2(20), 
    HIRE_DATE DATE CONSTRAINT EMP_HIRE_DATE_NN NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    JOB_ID VARCHAR2(10) CONSTRAINT EMP_JOB_NN NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    SALARY NUMBER(8,2), 
    COMMISSION_PCT NUMBER(2,2), 
    MANAGER_ID NUMBER(6,0), 
    DEPARTMENT_ID NUMBER(4,0));
```

And let's ask those questions for the employees, for their salaries. And we'll group those by the JOB they have.

So instead of by Category, we're doing by JOB_ID.

Since we want numbers across a range of TYPES of employees, we need to use the GROUP BY clause.

The functions are called by name, against the column, e.g. func(col) in the SELECT portion of the query.

```
SELECT
    job_id,
    SUM(salary),
    AVG(salary),
    MIN(salary),
    MAX(salary)
FROM
    employees
GROUP BY
    job_id
order by 2 desc, 3 desc
```

This gives us something like this:

[image]